# Find elements by 'class' ONLY within a particualr 'id' with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am new to scraping & I am trying to scrape data from a simple static web page.
The webpage is arranged in tables & I want to get the data only from within `id` 'Table1' (Red rectangle within the picture). However, I am unable to achieve this.

I want the contents of 'LabelColumn' & 'DataColumn', but only within 'Table1'
When I do `find_elements_by_class_name("LabelColumn")` & `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("DataColumn")` I get the 'LabelColumn' & 'DataColumn' data for the whole page & this is not what I want (it creates unnecessary data & takes more time).
Can any one guide on how to do it? I tried looking up `xpath` but i am getting errors that items not present, I think i am doing something wrong.

The Blue rectangle show only a couple of 'LabelColumn' & 'DataColumn' within 'Table1'. There are more of these inside the Green rectangle. I have collapsed those to reduce the size of the picture).

[image]

**Update**
Tried code (this still gives the content of the whole page & not jsut the content of element 'Table1'

```
table1 = driver.find_element_by_id("Table1")
labels = table1.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[@class='LabelColumn']")
contents = table1.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[@class='DataColumn']")
```

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: screenshot is of the webpage & not the code. I have pasted the code in proper format.

Comment: HTML is also code and should not be in a screenshot. Screenshots of the UI are fine, screenshots of code/HTML is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below xpath.

```
//table[@id='Table1']//td[@class='LabelColumn']
//table[@id='Table1']//td[@class='DataColumn']
```

or the following css

```
table[id='Table1'] .LabelColumn
table[id='Table1'] .DataColumn
```

Comment: The proper way to do IDs in a CSS selector is `#`, e.g. `#Table1 .LabelColumn`